# Why does it mean to say a quantum state's "penetration" is comparable to the distance over which it fluctuates?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, semiclassical

Consider the following diagram of an energy eigenstate in a harmonic potential.

[image]

The textbook from which I got this image says

> Also, in the classical limit the quantum mechanical probability density does not penetrate a measurable distance outside the region where $[V(x)-E]$ is negative because the penetration distance is comparable to the distance in which it fluctuates.

What does it mean by *"penetration distance is comparable to the distance in which it fluctuates"?*

Comment: Unless the author explains somewhere what he means by that ... I'd go out and get a new quantum mechanics book.   Not that it's wrong, but what good is an explanation if the explanation needs an explanation?  I could *guess* what it means, but guessing is no good.

Comment: Please add a reference for the image. Further, it would be nice of you to distill the problem out of the text the next time. Have you looked through the book for a definition of classical limit? Does the author give a formula for the probability density? Please add a few clarifications to your post.

Comment: Eisberg R.,Resnick R. -Quantum physics of atoms,molecules,solids,nuclei, and particles - Wiley. page no:159 (chapter 5)

Answer (score 1):

The authors probably mean:

The penetration depth of the wave function (i.e. how deep the
particle penetrates into the classically forbidden region)
is roughly equal to the wavelength in the oscillatory part.
See the two red marked distances in the image below.

[image]

Analyzing the eigenfunctions $\psi_n(x)$ you can indeed show
that these two distances are both roughly proportional to
$\sqrt{\frac{h}{nm\omega}}$ (at least for $n\gg 1)$.

Answer (score 0):

Think about the classical limit as dealing with large objects like a ball bouncing back and forth between two walls. Now the ball is made up of many atoms that have empty space in them. The wall also have this empty space too. Now given these two facts you can see that it is possible for the ball to go a couple atoms deep into the wall.

What the Author is trying to say that even if the ball goes that couple atoms width into the wall it does not compare to the distance the ball is travelling back and forth between the two walls. So the penetration distance(a couple atom widths) is very small compared to the distance the ball travels. With this fact you can approximate the probability of the ball being past the wall to be zero.

Comment: I really don't think that's what the author means. I think "the distance over which it fluctuates" means essentially the spatial period of the oscillating wavefunction.